# Import categories programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, import

I have 250+ categories and sub categories with me. I want to import it in my magento 2. It is not possible to manually add it. Can anyone help me with some scripts or code to import categories from csv.  Please dont reccomend any extension unless it is free.

Answer (score 1):

Check below link maybe that'll help you:

> https://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-import-a-category-with-its-subcategories-programmatically/

And create a module as per the instruction.

This will Import a category with its subcategories programmatically.

I also suggest you to remove/disable this module once you have successfully imported category.

Comment: I tried this. but does not work. There is some issue with this module. It displays blank page.